# How to Change Thunderbird sidebar icons

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, icon-themes

Everything about `Thunderbird` in 18.04 is right for me. The only thing that stands odd is the left sidebar icons which look very old.Is there any method to change this ? And use `Font Awesome` or `Material Icons`. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Full themes are no longer supported in Thunderbird, but there is one icon theme that still works. It's [Phoenity icons](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/phoenity-icons/?src=search). However this is not based on Font Awesome or Material Icons.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mind, I add my alternate answer. `Monterail Dark` looks much finer than `Phoenity` icons and it is a full theme, a modern one. I will let users choose between the options. There is a darker variant as well which works on the latest version of Thunderbird v68.

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/monterail-dark/

[image]

Don't go by the screenshot, Moneterail Dark is available for English as well.